# Use ssl certificate of the server instead of root CA certificate while making HTTPS calls using urllib3

Tags: python, ssl, urllib3

It is given in the documentation of [urllib3](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#certificate-verification) that,

**In order to enable verification you will need a set of root certificates.**

but is there any way to make HTTPS calls by using the SSL certificate of the server itself instead of root certificates.

Comment: The is a good reason for having trusted root certificates. Self signed certs will only be "trusted" if you install it locally.

Comment: *"...but is there any way to verify the SSL certificate of the server itself instead of root certificates."* - I think you are missing essential concepts. The root certificates are not verified. There are considered trusted and then used as the trust anchor to verify the server certificates.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. For suppose ssl certificate of the server is 'A' and root certificate is 'R'. At present I am able to make HTTPS calls if I have 'R', but not If have only 'A'. If there are two servers which have the same root certificate, both of them will be verified if we use only 'R' but if take 'A' in to consideration we can reject the calls to others.

Answer (score 1):

urllib3 has a property of the ***PoolManager*** called ***assert_fingerprint***: this property can be initiated with a string that is the hex-encoded digest of the certificate bytes. When used, this will circumvent the regular chain building logic.